# jquery accordion input focus when changing tabs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jquery ui accordion (1.10.2).  I have a single long form spanning across the accordion.  The behavior I'd like to see is that when changing tabs, the first form field in the active tab should be focused upon.  I am stumped on how to do this.

In addition to the basic accordion, I've also added pieces so that the top of the active tab scrolls to the top of the screen, and I've added next/prev buttons for added navigation.

```
        $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion(
                { header: "h3",          
                autoheight: false,
                heightStyle: "content",
                active: false,
                alwaysOpen: false,
                fillspace: false,
                collapsible: false,
                clearStyle: true,
                //heightStyle: content   //auto, fill, content
                activate: function (event, ui) {
                    var scrollTop = $(".accordion").scrollTop();
                    if(!ui.newHeader.length) return;
                    var top = $(ui.newHeader).offset().top;
                    $("html,body").animate({
                        scrollTop: scrollTop + top - 35
                    }, "fast");
                    }
                });
            $('#accordion button').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();
                var delta = ($(this).is('.next') ? 1 : -1);
                $('#accordion').accordion('option', 'active', ( $('#accordion').accordion('option','active') + delta  ));
            });

        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you using tabs with accordion?